# Using joblib to merge multiple Dataframes from list

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, append, joblib

I would like to merge multiple DataFrames stored in a List in to one DataFrame by using joblib / multiprocessing.

All DataFrames in list have the same columns.

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['alice','jenny','bob','tom'],
                  'age':[12,15,18,21]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john','john','chris','chris'],
                  'age':[23,46,32,56]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['bobby','kenny','jenna','joe'],
                  'age':[66,55,44,33]})

lst = [df0, df1, df2]

target_df = pd.DataFrame()

def merge_df(df):
    return target_df.append(df)

Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(merge_df)(x) for x in lst)
```

This gives me only a list of lists and target_df is empty.

Comment: Why do you want to use `joblib`? Merging iteratively will be less efficient than merging once, so why not directly use `target_df = pd.concat(lst)`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your suggestion and found that it isnt neccessary to multiprocess merging dataframes ^^. But there is a caviat afterwards when writing merged dataframe in to disk as a excelfile, that takes too long -.-

Comment: That is however independent of the merging, the time needed is… the time needed…